# Test Anova on multiple groups

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

I would like to use this code to compare the means between my entire dataframe:

`F_statistic, pVal = stats.f_oneway(percentage_age_ss.iloc[:,0:1], 
                                   percentage_age_ss.iloc[:,1:2],
                                   percentage_age_ss.iloc[:,2:3],
                                  percentage_age_ss.iloc[:,3:4]) etc...`

However, I don't want to use each time .iloc because it takes too much time. Do you I have another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Not referring to efficiency but as for time programming you can use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

get a list of columns using list comprehension, then use star syntax to expand it into the arglist:

```
stats.f_oneway(*(percentage_age_ss[col] for col in percentage_age_ss.columns))
```

or, just

```
stats.f_oneway(*(percentage_age_ss.T.values))
```